# I can't get http sevlet response from backend with springboot 2.0

Tags: java, linux

I am using springboot 2.0.0.RELEASE, I just migrated from springboot 1.5.1

I have below code to filter bad login in springboot:

```
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
throws IOException, ServletException {
   response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
}
```

above code will filter the bad login and send error to frontend WEB client.

In springboot 1.5.1, the error in the response will contain JSON body, such as:

```
{"timestamp":1523253790780,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Autentication failed.","path":"/login"}
```

but when I use springboot 2.0, I can't get HTTP response, and I got error complain the error= null from the web client, I don't know where to look for  the problem.
I use tomcat-embed 8.5.28 and jackson jar version for 2.9.4, if I remove above `sendError`, just use `PrintWriter` in response to add `JSON` string for myself, it works, so the issue i suppose is the `sendError` method not working for me in springboot 2.0.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a visible stacktrace on the server side that you can share with us?

Comment: Thank you Venantius. Actually I do try catch for the sendError but I don't get some exception, from the Web Client, I can get the status code with 401, but the error=null and the message was not I want too,  from  Chrome, I saw the http response is empty, just leave some js error in the chrome console.

Comment: the incoming login request was filtered by our internal code and we throw exception and let Spring BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint handle it. we override BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint and write commence method and prepare the sendError to client, but client can't get the http response body